# How can I create a multipage PDF from JPG's in Preview?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I just upgraded to Lion recently. When I was on Snow Leopard, creating a multi-page PDF document in Preview was simple:

1. I would open up the image
2. Save it as a PDF
3. Open up the PDF
4. Open up the panel that displays pages (on the left)(Menu:View/Thumbnails)
5. Drag and drop images on this "page panel" below the first image
6. Save the file again.

This would create a multi-page PDF file where each page is an image.

I've tried doing the same thing in Lion, but it doesn't produce the same results. Although in step 5 it appears as though a multipage document is created, after you save it, the file size becomes much bigger than the original one page PDF, but after opening it, all you can see is a single page.

Is there any way to do this in Lion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oops, just tried it again. The problem was that I was dropping the files below the page rather than on the page thumbnail.

Comment: Weird that Apple changed it to a seemingly less intuitive way, but thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I did this, but the first JPG fills the whole page while the rest of the pages have a white border around the original image.

Answer (score 54):

This works for me on Mountain Lion:

1. Open all the JPG's in Preview so that the files are selectable within the one window, i.e. thumbnails of the JPG's are viewable in the selection pane located the window's left side.
2. Click in the selection pane and select all the thumbnails with Cmd-A.
3. Select File > Print... from the menu bar.
4. Select PDF > (from the drop down) Save as PDF... from within the Print Dialog.

   [image: Save as PDF]
5. Take it from there...

Answer (score 6):

I think I found an easier way with Lion:

1. Select all images and right click, choose Open with Preview.
2. Select all images inside Preview (cmd+a) and right click, Export as…
3. Choose a folder where all the new .pdf files will be saved.
4. Open one of the .pdf files in Preview, and drag n'drop the all the other files over the Thumbnail of the current file in Preview.

Comment: this does not make a multi-page PDF

Answer (score 3):

We are using Snow Leopard and having the same results as Daniel Serodio, i.e. the first page looks good (no border) while all the following pages have an annoying white border around the image.

The only workaround we found adds another step to the process.

1. Open all jpegs in Preview and display the sidebar. The jpegs will display in one window but still be separate files, as discussed above.
2. Select all the thumbnails in the sidebar (Command-A.)
3. Right-click in the sidebar area and choose Save a Copy to Folder. In the following dialog, choose PDF for the format, and choose a place to save the PDFs. Preview saves the jpegs as individual PDFs to your selected folder.
4. Close out of the jpegs and open the LAST of the PDFs you just made* and display the sidebar. Now follow steps as above: select all of the rest of the PDFs in the Finder, and drag them ONTO the page thumbnail icon in the sidebar of Preview to get a multi-page PDF.
5. Save!

*For some reason Preview is kicking this "seed" PDF to the end when I add the additional PDF files, so that's why I'm saying start with your last page instead of the first page, so you don't have to re-order them again.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me on Yosemite 10.10. Need to be sure to drop the images you want to add to the pdf ON the thumbnail not below as another person mentioned.

I was sending images to my brother who is on a pc (not sure if that matters).
He said he had to click on each picture and say save as...asked if I could make it a pdf then he could just click once to save a set. 
Could have just sent him a zipped file but the idea of creating a pdf interested me, found this and it worked.
Thanks to the original poster of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an external tool such as http://www.from-jpg-to-pdf.com/ which is a website designed to easily convert `.jpg` to `.pdf`.

Answer (score -1):

Apple's built-in Preview application (free) alone sufficient to make small changes in PDF documents. When you double click on any PDF file, it opens, by default, in Preview. You can use Preview app to merge, split, mark up, annotate, and sign PDF files. Preview is the easiest solution to view, create and edit PDF documents on Mac.

With long documents or for complex editing tasks, third-party PDF editors like PDFPen or [this one](http://bit.do/http-www-mypdfsolutions-com-advance-pdf-editor-mac-html) (cheap alternative to PDFPen) are the best bet.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. If you could detail how to do so with PDFPen that'd be good.